# How to build a new list base on another file and sort it in a certain way

Tags: r

I have a list that contain multiple files, that looks like this:
[image]

Now I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

```
structure(list(Order = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Data = c("Bone Scan", "Brain Scan", 
"", "Cancer History")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I build a new data list which only contain the data that is in `df$Data` and stored in the order that appears in `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to subset `datalist` using `df$Data`. It should give data in the same order as `df$Data`.

```
result <- datalist[df$Data]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if df$Data has NA, how can we remove NULL set?

Comment: How can I filter NA out df$Data?

Comment: `datalist[na.omit(df$Data)]`

Comment: Thanks so much. :) if I want to manually add a data.frame `test`  into or remove `Bone Scan` from the new list `result`, what should I do?

Comment: To add you can do : `datalist[c(na.omit(df$Data), 'test')]` and to remove ``datalist[setdiff(na.omit(df$Data), 'BoneScan')]``

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `pluck`

```
library(purrr)
datalist %>%
     pluck(df$Data)
```